# How to submit a form to server (aspx) and get csv file from server (aspx) wtih python?

Tags: python, asp.net, csv, python-requests

I need to submit a form to the server and get csv file from the server via the internet with python.

The server website is (http:// 222.158.245.253/obweb/data/c1/c1_output6.aspx?LocationNo=012), which publishes the observation data of sea in Japan.

This is html souce code.

```
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <head><title>
                大阪湾水質定点自動観測データ配信システム
            </title><link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../../js/javascript.js" charset="Shift_JIS"></script>

              <script language="JavaScript" src="../../js/jkl-calendar.js" charset="Shift_JIS"></script>
              <script language="JavaScript">
                  var cal1 = new JKL.Calendar("calid1", "form1", "dummy");
                  var cal2 = new JKL.Calendar("calid2", "form1", "dummy");

                  function checkUpdate() {
                      return checkInputC1("6");
                  }
              </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="c1_output6.aspx?LocationNo=012" id="aspnetForm">
            <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
            </div>

            <div>

                <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="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" />
            </div>
                <table id="output_main" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top">
                            <span id="ctl00_lblTitle" class="output_page_label_1">大阪港波浪観測塔 データダウンロード</span>
                            <hr color="#0066CC">
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><span id="ctl00_lblMessage" class="output_page_message">　</span></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                          <table border="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="3">
                                <span class="output_page_label_1">条件指定</span>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="70" height="30"><span class="output_page_label_2">観測項目</span></td>
                              <td>
                                <select name="ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuKomoku" id="ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuKomoku" style="height:22px;width:120px;">
                <option value="17">全ての水質項目</option>
                <option value="1">　 水温</option>
                <option value="2">　 塩分</option>
                <option value="3">　 光量子</option>
                <option value="5">　 DO飽和度</option>
                <option value="6">　 濁度</option>
                <option value="7">　 クロロフィルa</option>
                <option value="16">風向・風速</option>
                <option value="15">流向・流速</option>

            </select>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="90" height="30" valign="middle">
                                <div style="float: left;">
                                  <span class="output_page_label_2">観測日</span>
                                </div>
                                <div style="float: right;">
                                  <img src="../../img/cal.png" class="link" onClick="cal1.reset(); cal1.write('ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuYearFrom', 'ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuMonthFrom', 'ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuDayFrom');"><br>
                                  <div id="calid1"></div>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="320">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuYearFrom" id="ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuYearFrom" style="height:22px;width:60px;">
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2014">2014</option>

            </select>
                                      <span class="output_page_label_2">年</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuMonthFrom" id="ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuMonthFrom" style="height:22px;width:40px;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>

            </select>
                                      <span class="output_page_label_2">月</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuDayFrom" id="ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuDayFrom" style="height:22px;width:40px;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>

            </select>
                                      <span class="output_page_label_2">日　から</span>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="90" height="30" align="right">
                                <img src="../../img/cal.png" class="link" onClick="cal2.reset(); cal2.write('ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuYearTo', 'ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuMonthTo', 'ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuDayTo');"><br>
                                <div id="calid2"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="320">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuYearTo" id="ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuYearTo" style="height:22px;width:60px;">
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2014">2014</option>

            </select>
                                      <span class="output_page_label_2">年</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuMonthTo" id="ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuMonthTo" style="height:22px;width:40px;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>

            </select>
                                      <span class="output_page_label_2">月</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <select name="ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuDayTo" id="ctl00_cphBody_cboKansokuDayTo" style="height:22px;width:40px;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>

            </select>
                                      <span class="output_page_label_2">日　まで</span>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                        <td>
                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$cphBody$btnGetData" id="ctl00_cphBody_btnGetData" src="../../img/get_data.png" onclick="return checkUpdate();" style="height:40px;width:92px;border-width:0px;" />
                        </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td height="5"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2" height="50" align="center">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                        <td height="400">
                          <iframe id="ctl00_cphBody_downloadFrame" style="width: 0px; height: 0px" name="downloadframe" frameborder="no"></iframe>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                  <input name="ctl00$txtPageID" type="hidden" id="ctl00_txtPageID" value="GxTYgjyWPW" />
                </table>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

So far, I always select the item and the date and click the download button on the lower right. Then, When a file save dialog box is displayed, I preserve the csv file from the server.

I would like to automate these manual labors with python. I have studied about python and web scraping and have used python modules(like BeautifulSoup). However, This website is difficult to do web scraping due to "aspx".

This is a python source code which I made.

```
import requests

url = "http://222.158.245.253/obweb/data/c1/c1_output6.aspx?LocationNo=012"
payload = {'LocationNo':'012',
           'ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuKomoku':'3',
           'ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuYearFrom':'2013',
           'ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuMonthFrom':'6',
           'ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuDayFrom':'1',
           'ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuYearTo':'2014',
           'ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuMonthTo':'6',
           'ctl00$cphBody$cboKansokuDayTo':'30'
          }

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
r.text
print r.content
with open("requests_results.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
print r.content
```

However, I can't get a csv file where obaserbation data is preserved but can get html file.

Please try these manual labors and help me to automate these labors.

Comment: The issue of scraping asp sites with Python was covered in a recent blog post here:  https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition/ 
It has a pretty comprehensive write up of the issue (with how ASP handles form data) as well as some code examples using Scrapy to handle this .  (The solution is similar to one from @deostroll, Scrapy has some convenience methods that make it easy to handle).

Answer (score 0):

I've used `urllib2` module for this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://localhost:58123/webform1.aspx';
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

f = open('result.html', 'w')
f.write(the_page)
f.close()
```

And it works. However I've just returned plain text generated in the server. You can make your web server send back a csv file.